# Fitting a beta mixed model

Tags: beta-regression

I would like some clarification on fitting a beta mixed model.

My dependent variable is the proportion of days that patients take medication. For every patient(Patient.ID), the pharmacy either had an intervention or no intervention (Int_code of 0/1). below is my model

```
library(glmmTMB)

Model5 <- glmmTMB(Proportion ~ Int_Name + (1|Patient.ID), data, family=list(family="beta",link="logit"))
```

I keep getting the the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your problem is that the proportion is sometimes 0 or 1, which is a problem, because of the logit link function (you end of taking the log of 0 in either case). You can avoid such issues by using a random effects logistic regression that models the number of days directly instead of the proportion. Then you could do this with the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package: `glm( cbind(days_taken, days_not_taken) ~ Int_Name + (1|Patient.ID), family = binomial(link="logit"))`.

Comment: Bjorn. 

This was really helpful I really appreciate your assistance. I really should have asked for help sooner. Things make sense now.